# How can I reduce the complexity of my dictionary solution to Codility Max Counters

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

I was really pleased with finding such a simple solution, up until I got hammered on the complexity. What can I do to reduce the complexity, if anything with this or do I need to find a different method?

The problem:

You are given N counters, initially set to 0, and you have two possible operations on them:

increase(X) − counter X is increased by 1,
max counter − all counters are set to the maximum value of any counter.
A non-empty array A of M integers is given. This array represents consecutive operations:

`if A[K] = X, such that 1 ≤ X ≤ N`, then operation K is increase(X),
`if A[K] = N + 1` then operation K is max counter.
For example, given integer N = 5 and array A such that:

```
A[0] = 3
A[1] = 4
A[2] = 4
A[3] = 6
A[4] = 1
A[5] = 4
A[6] = 4
```

the values of the counters after each consecutive operation will be:

```
(0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 2, 0)
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
(3, 2, 2, 2, 2)
(3, 2, 2, 3, 2)
(3, 2, 2, 4, 2)
```

The goal is to calculate the value of every counter after all operations.

Write a function:

```
def solution(N, A)
```

that, given an integer N and a non-empty array A consisting of M integers, returns a sequence of integers representing the values of the counters.

The resulting array should be returned as an array of integers.

For example, given:

```
A[0] = 3
A[1] = 4
A[2] = 4
A[3] = 6
A[4] = 1
A[5] = 4
A[6] = 4
```

the function should return [3, 2, 2, 4, 2], as explained above.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N and M are integers within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..N + 1].

My solution has complexity O(N*M)

```
def solution(N,A):

    # Step 1 - initialise
    counter = [0]*N
    counter_label = list(range(1,N+1))

    counter_dict = dict(zip(counter_label,counter))    

    # Step 2a iterate through A
    for i in range(len(A)):
        # Step 2B step through each counter
        for l in counter_label:
            if A[i] > N:
                counter_dict[l] = max(counter_dict.values())
            if A[i] == l:
                counter_dict[l] += 1
    return list(counter_dict.values())
```

My function produces the correct solution for the example, but times out for massive arrays:

```
A = [3,4,4,6,1,4,4]
N = 5
print(solution(N,A))
```

[3, 2, 2, 4, 2]

Comment: What problem is your algorithm meant to solve? "Codility Max Counters" doesn't mean anything to people unfamiliar with the problem, so please edit your question to explain this (don't just add a link).

Comment: Also, your code is just a function definition. Please post a [mre] with example inputs and expected output

Comment: Thanks! Updated with your feedback

Answer (score 2):

The naive implementation of this is to store the counters in a list, answer an "increase" query by incrementing the counter at that index in O(1) time, and answer a "max" query by finding the maximum and updating every counter in O(N) time. That means answering M queries takes O(MN) time. With up to 100,000 queries and up to 100,000 counters, O(MN) time is not good enough.

Your implementation is actually significantly worse than that, since you answer an "increase" query by iterating over all counters in O(N) time, and you answer a "max" query by iterating over all counters *and recomputing the maximum on every iteration*, taking O(N<sup>2</sup>) time per "max" query. That means your overall time complexity is O(MN<sup>2</sup>).

---

To achieve linear time you need to be able to answer each query in O(1) amortized time. That means answering the "max" query without iterating over every counter. One way is to store the counters in a dictionary, and keep track of the current and previous maximum.

- To answer an "increase" query, increment the counter in the dictionary, using the previous maximum as a fallback for the counter if it's not present in the dictionary, and update the current maximum if appropriate.
- To answer a "max" query, replace the dictionary with a new empty one, and update the previous maximum.

Here's an implementation:

```py
def solution(N, A):
    counters = dict()
    current_max, prev_max = 0, 0
    for q in A:
        if q == N + 1:
            # max query
            counters = dict()
            prev_max = current_max
        else:
            # increase query
            c = counters.get(q, prev_max) + 1
            counters[q] = c
            current_max = max(current_max, c)
    # return the counters as a list
    return [counters.get(i, prev_max) for i in range(1, N+1)]
```

Replacing the dictionary takes O(1) amortized time; although it creates O(n) work for the garbage collector when the dictionary's size is n, this can be amortized across the Ω(n) "increase" queries that must have happened to make the dictionary that large. Therefore, answering M queries of any kinds takes O(M) time. At the end, we need to build a list of the counter values, which takes O(N) time, but this only needs to be done once.

Therefore, the overall time complexity is O(M + N), linear time. This is [asymptotically optimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotically_optimal_algorithm), because you have to do *something* for each of M queries, and you have to output a list of size N.

Comment: I think you could also do max queries in O(1), i.e., non-amortized, by not resetting the dict and instead maxing at read: https://repl.it/repls/BurlyGracefulError

Comment: Oh and another version with amortized O(1): https://repl.it/repls/WoodenElderlyDeeplearning

Comment: @HeapOverflow Yes, although anything involving adding to a dict or list is O(1) amortized because of having to reallocate the underlying array sometimes.

Comment: Right. Though the max query in my first suggestion doesn't do that, so at least that part really is O(1). Anyway, posted my second version and yet another one as an answer now. I quite like Codility, haven't used it before, but their evaluation pages look neat and can apparently be shared.

Comment: You can get a "real" O(1) on both queries if you use a list instead of a dictionary, but it's not a real gain because it takes O(N) time to initialise the list. There's also a solution that uses "timestamps" to avoid clearing the dictionary; you insert a pair `(val, t)` in the dictionary, increment the variable `t` instead of clearing the dictionary, and only use `val` if the "timestamp" it's paired with equals the current value of `t`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution based on [@kaya3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60592052/12671057). He's basically implementing a defaultdict himself, here I just use Python's. [Got 100% on Codility](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingX6MXQ4-MCN/).

```
from collections import defaultdict

def solution(N, A):
    counters = defaultdict(int)
    for a in A:
        if a <= N:
            counters[a] += 1
        elif counters:
            counters = defaultdict(max(counters.values()).__int__)
    return [counters[i] for i in range(1, N+1)]
```

Another version, also [got 100% on Codility](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingJTCGM7-JVV/):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def solution(N, A):
    default = 0
    counters = defaultdict(lambda: default)
    for a in A:
        if a <= N:
            counters[a] += 1
        elif counters:
            default = max(counters.values())
            counters.clear()
    return [counters[i] for i in range(1, N+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently completed this here is my 100 percent solution.

```
def solution(N,A):
# write your code in Python 3.6

counter = [0]*N
max_counter = 0
if len(set(A) - set([N+1])) == 0:
  return counter
for k in range(len(A)):
    if A[k]==N+1:
            counter = [max_counter]*N
    else:
        if A[k]-1 <=N -1:
            counter[A[k]-1]+=1
            if counter[A[k]-1]>max_counter:
                max_counter= counter[A[k]-1]
            
return counter
```